# Why can't I save the new textbox value to a txt?

Tags: php, file, variables, textbox

The code perfectly reads the content of a txt file and sends it to the textbox named "text_box", but when I modify the textbox and want to save, it does not save and reload the original value of the txt in the textbox. How can I solve it?

```
<?php

$textoo = file_get_contents('demo.txt');
echo '<html>';
echo    '<body>';
echo        '<form name="form" method="post">';
echo            '<input type="text" name="text_box" value='.$textoo.' size="50"/>';
echo       '</form>';
echo        '<form name="form" method="post">';
echo            '<input type="submit" name="guardarr" value="Guardar">';
echo       '</form>';
echo    '</body>';
echo '</html>';


if(array_key_exists('guardarr',$_POST)){
   guardar();
}

function guardar(){
    if(isset($_POST['text_box'])) { //only do file operations when appropriate
        $a = $_POST['text_box'];
        $myFile = "demo.txt";
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
        fwrite($fh, $a);
        fclose($fh);
    }
}   


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont't need two forms inside HTML and send its value. It should have been

```
<?php
echo '<html>';
echo    '<body>';
echo        '<form name="form" method="post">';
echo            '<input type="text" name="text_box" value='.$textoo.' size="50"/>';

             // Deleted form content here
echo            '<input type="submit" name="guardarr" value="Guardar">';
echo       '</form>';
echo    '</body>';
echo '</html>';
?>
```